# Python implementation of find_all_indexes

Tags: python, algorithm, strings, interview-questions, reinventing-the-wheel

I got asked this question before in an interview.

For example, `find_all_indexes('ababc', 'abc')` returns `2`. This Python function should find the index of first occurrence pattern. I also wrote a function that returns a list of starting indexes of all occurrences of the pattern in a text.

I have the following implementation that handles most of the cases:

```
def find_all_indexes(text, pattern):
    indexes = []
    text_index = 0
    while text_index != len(text):
        if pattern == '':
            indexes.append(text_index)
        else:
            for i in range(len(pattern)):
                if text_index + i < len(text):
                    if text[text_index + i] != pattern[i]:
                        break
                    if i == len(pattern) - 1:
                        indexes.append(text_index)
        text_index += 1
    return indexes

def test_string_algorithms(text, pattern):
    indexes = find_all_indexes(text, pattern)
    print('find_all_indexes({!r}, {!r}) => {}'.format(text, pattern, indexes))

def main():
    test_string_algorithms(text, pattern)
    print('Usage: {} text pattern'.format(script))
    print("find_all_indexes('abra cadabra', 'abra') => [0, 8]")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am not sure if I exhausted all of the edge cases, but I ran [this unit test](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/85f73244f943d55cc9ac7a9b69444ed7), and it passed all tests.

The pytest output:

```
pytest test.py
======================= test session starts ========================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.12, pytest-3.0.5, py-1.4.32, pluggy-0.4.0

collected 3 items 

test.py .........

===================== 3 passed in 0.07 seconds
```

Comment: (Welcome to CR!) Do you want opinions with respect to "interview setting" or "best code ever"? First thing I notice: neither comments nor [doc strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

Comment: The explanation is pretty confusing (at least from my point of view). It seems like we have a `find_all_indexes` function returning an integer and another function which does return all indices...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code looks correct but overly complicated for the naïve algorithm used.

For a first refactor, you could pull out the special case `pattern == ''`. (We might pull it back in later).

Then

> ```
>             for i in range(len(pattern)):
>                 if text_index + i < len(text):
>                     if text[text_index + i] != pattern[i]:
>                         break
>                     if i == len(pattern) - 1:
>                         indexes.append(text_index)
> ```

is just a substring equality check. There are two things to note here:

1. Since it fails when `text_index + len(pattern) > len(text)` the outer loop runs too far.
2. This could be written as `if text[text_index:text_index+len(pattern)] == pattern: indexes.append(text_index)`.

Thirdly, the outer `while` loop could be written as a `for` `in` `range`, which is more Pythonic.

Putting those together, we have

```
def find_all_indexes(text, pattern):
    if pattern == '':
        return range(len(text) + 1)

    indexes = []
    for text_index in range(len(text) - len(pattern) + 1):
        if text[text_index : text_index + len(pattern)] == pattern:
            indexes.append(text_index)
    return indexes
```

But then the Pythonic way to write a `for` `if` `append` loop like that is a comprehension:

```
def find_all_indexes(text, pattern):
    if pattern == '':
        return range(len(text) + 1)

    return [text_index for text_index in range(len(text) - len(pattern) + 1)
            if text[text_index : text_index + len(pattern)] == pattern]
```

And now the special case is really a microoptimisation, and could possibly be removed to leave a one-liner.

---

However, that's not the final word. Naïve string search is asymptotically inferior to techniques such as Knuth-Morris-Pratt string search. You probably shouldn't roll your own KMP routine, but you could use `string.find` to get the benefit. So a better implementation would be a loop around `string.find`.

Comment: (Boohoo. This leaves out substituting `for:…else:` for *`for:…if iteration_variable >= upper_limit - step:`*.)

Comment: @greybeard, you've lost me. The only instance of `>=` I can find anywhere on this page is in your comment.

Comment: For all I can tell five weeks later and counting, I tried to jest about your diligent stepwise improvement: after correcting the outer loop range, the inner loop could be `for i in range(len(pattern)):
            if text[text_index + i] != pattern[i]:
                break
        else:
            indexes.append(text_index)`.

Comment: A couple of remarks: [+] To me, the assumption that the input and pattern are members of `<class 'str'> ` is not warranted by the specification for the function. [+] It possible to simplify `if pattern == '':` to `if pattern:`.  [+] The behavior when `!pattern` is undefined as are many other behaviors such as when `pattern` is an integer.

Answer (score 3):

#### Remarks on the specification

Though the example pattern uses strings as the argument, *the possibility of other input types such as lists is left open.* This suggests further development of the test suite to cover a variety of cases. In the context of a technical interview, an example test case using lists may be enough to suggest the candidate has thought about the problem as generalized pattern matching.

#### General Notes on the code

**Naming:** `indexes` is a good name. `text` is not for because it biases the approach to pattern matching toward only strings.

**Variables:** Declaring more names such as `text_len = len(text)` might make the code easier to read and understand. It tells the reader that the length of `text` is important and it un-nests trivial code from within the more complex and important logic. Sometimes that reader is you.

**Code shape:** One of the benefits of Python's semantic indentation is that it provides visual evidence of logical complexity by pushing code to the right as it becomes more convoluted. Deep indentation suggests refactoring (no matter how wide the programmer's monitor is). Think of deep indentation as a Python [*code smell*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). The deeper the indentation the harder it is for the reader to maintain the context of its execution.

**Comments:** Please.  Most code is not self explanatory to someone reading it six weeks from now. That someone could be you. Comments are a way to root out assumptions implicit in the code. For example `if pattern == '':` implies that the input is a string. Without the assumption it can be `if pattern:`.

**`Main`:** A great idea. Providing well formatted text makes working in the interpreter much better.

#### Using Python features

Though I like C, I usually prefer Python. The code looks a lot like C. Python makes it easy to write code that looks like C. That doesn't mean code that looks like C is a good thing.

- Python has [slices](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html). Unfortunately, [C does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618342/copying-a-subset-of-an-array-into-another-array-array-slicing-in-c). Slices will simplify the Python code. Slices will make the logic less complex.
- Python has documentation strings. [`docstrings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) provide high level access to the descriptions of the code you write. See remarks on commenting above.

#### Alternative Implementation

It is worth noting that this implementation was written at leisure. There was not the pressure of a technical interview. It was not written while the primary concern was getting a job. There was time to drink coffee and think. There was time to take a walk and think. There was time to refactor in my favorite editor.

```
1:  def find_all_indexes(source, pattern):
2:     output = []
3:     length_source = len(source)
4:     length_pattern = len(pattern)
5:     for i in range(length_source):
6:         if source[i] == pattern[0] and source[i:i+length_pattern] == pattern:
7:             output.append(i)
8:         if i + length_pattern > length_source:
9:             break
10:    return output
```

**1:** The name `source` is as type agnostic as `pattern`. I would have used `input` but it is the name of a built in Python function. This can affect syntax highlighting in the editor.

**2:** I don't believe in self documenting code, but calling the output `output` is an exception.

**6:** The `and` short circuits. The slice covers all the logic of what to do when `pattern[0]` is matched in the source.

**8:** This bit of cleverness is why the absence of comments makes code harder to understand.

**Remarks:** The code does not have a code path for a null/false pattern. Based on the specification, I consider it undefined behavior. There are some things I like about C. Practically speaking, in the context of an interview, "What happens with null pattern?" might be an interesting request for more information...then again, what happens if the pattern is not iterable suggests that treating it as undefined behavior might be reasonable in the context of a technical interview.